# how to enable JavaScript on IE8?

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, struts2

I want to enable JavaScript on IE 8 but it does not work.
I tried this way:
Internet options/security/(select Internet zone) custom level
Enable active scripting
but it does not work.
Is there any solution to active javascript on browser when my application running?
My web application uses struts2

Comment: How do you know that javascript on IE does not work? How do you know that error is in IE settings and not in your own application?

Comment: because it works on google chrome

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Struts2. Also, chances are that there is a problem with your JavaScript and not with the browser settings. Just because JavaScript runs in Chrome doesn't mean it will run in IE.

Comment: Funny thing, after searching in google land, the Microsoft page http://support.microsoft.com/gp/howtoscript that provides this help currently requires scripting to view the page.

Answer (score 4):

The following should enable scripting in Internet Explorer:

1. On the Tools menu, click Internet Options, and then click the Security tab.
2. Click the Internet zone.
3. Click Custom Level.
4. In the Security Settings – Internet Zone dialog box, click Enable for Active Scripting in the Scripting section.
5. Click the Back button to return to the previous page, and then click the Refresh button to run scripts.
   **Note**: To allow scripting on this Web site only, and to leave scripting disabled in the Internet zone, add this Web site to the Trusted sites zone. 
   Taken from: http://support.microsoft.com/gp/howtoscript

Comment: Add this line at the top of your page and run this page on internet explorer 8.It will allow javascript to work.

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1- strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir" />

Answer (score 0):

`Start > Run...` in the Run box, type in `regsvr32 jscript.dll`

You should receive a popup says that it registration succeeded. You then should be able to display JavaScript in your browser properly.

Comment: I have tried it but this error happend: the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80004005

Comment: I tried it as administrator and it was successful. but the javascript does not run again!!!

Comment: i think some error in ur javascript code thats y its not running ...show ur javascript code and html

Answer (score 0):

In IE8 its quite simple.

```
Tools-->Internet Options-->Advanced
```

In `setting` (Browsing options) unchecked the script options.Below the image.

[image]

Currently I am working on IE8 also.Its working.

Comment: debugging is debugging, no relation to running.. I tried it but it has failed